# Populating data from JSON for drop downs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js, marionette

I am receiving JSON from the server which looks like

```
{
    "accountType": ["Full","Trial"],
    "states": [
        {"state":"AL","stateDescription":"Alabama","featured":"A1"},
        {"state":"AK","stateDescription":"Alaska","featured":"B1"}
    ],
    "dates":[
        {"dateDescription":"Jan","month":1,"year":2008},
        {"dateDescription":"Feb","month":2,"year":2008}
    ]
}
```

In the Backbone file I'm doing:

```
define([ 'backbone', 'underscore', 'vent', ], function (Backbone, _, vent) {
    'use strict';

    return Backbone.Model.extend({

        url: {},

        loaded: false,

        defaults: {
            accountType: [],
            states: [],
            dates: [],
        },


        initialize: function () {
            this.on('change', this.change);
            var that = this;

            $.getJSON("webapp/jsondata", function (data) {
                that.set({
                    states: data.states.state,
                });
            });

            $.getJSON("webapp/jsondata", function (data) {
                that.set({
                    dates: data.dates.dateDescription,
                });
            });

            $.getJSON("webapp/jsondata", function (data) {
                that.set({
                    accountType: data.accountType,
                });
           });
        },  
    });
});
```

So each `$.getJSON` should get the relevant data and populate the backbone model defaults.

Except at the moment only the `account` type works.  I don't understand why this would work and the others wouldn't as it's the same code.  The only difference is in the JSON data, `accountType` has 2 pieces of data.  `States` has 3 and I only want to return one piece of this (`state`).

So I guess my issue is in specifying the data being retrieved in the `$.getJSON` code but many hours online have not revealed an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `states` and `dates` keys in your data are arrays, but you try to access them as hashes. 
If you want to extract the state keys from your states array, you can use [`_.pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) :

```
$.getJSON("webapp/jsondata", function (data) {
    that.set({
        states: _.pluck(data.states, 'state')
    });
});
```

With the data given, `_.pluck(data.states, 'state')` will give you `["AL", "AK"]`

Not that, as written, your model could be greatly simplified by using `model.fetch` with [`model.parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse). For example :

```
return Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "webapp/jsondata",
    loaded: false,
    defaults: function () {
        return {
            accountType: [],
            states: [],
            dates: [],
        };
    },

    parse: function (data) {
        return {
            accountType: data.accountType,
            states: _.pluck(data.states, 'state'),
            dates: _.pluck(data.dates, 'dateDescription')
        };
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.on('change', this.change);
        this.fetch();
    },  
});
```

And beware using arrays in a `defaults` hash, use a function instead.

Comment: Mate that's absolutely done it - perfect, i'm totally new to this backbone stuff and struggling my way through - you've sorted something i've spent hours looking at!  Cheers